# Windows 10: Getting the SMB version in use for a specific remote host?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, samba, smb, windows-networking

I have set up a SAMBA server on Ubuntu. I set the minimum protocol to SMB2, maximum to SMB3. Now, I can connect to the shared path from Windows, and I want to know which protocol (SMB2 or SMB3) Window is using. Is there any way to know that?

I have searched Google, but all I could find was the enabled versions of SMB on a Windows computer, not the version of SMB currently in use with a specific remote host. Let's say that I have opened a network-shared directory `\\mybackup\test\` with File Explorer. Can I know which version of SMB Windows is currently using for `mybackup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `Get-SmbConnection` from PowerShell to list all outgoing SMB connections, together with their "Dialect" (which is how SMB calls the protocol versions).

```
Get-SmbConnection

Get-SmbConnection -ServerName mybackup
```

It can also show whether the connection is encrypted, although this is not included by default:

```
Get-SmbConnection | ft ServerName,ShareName,Dialect,Encrypted,UserName
```

*(Don't confuse this command with Get-SmbSession which is for incoming connections.)*

---

You can also get this information on the server – Samba has a command `smbstatus` (requires root), which lists all inbound SMB connections like `Get-SmbSession` does on Windows.

```
$ sudo smbstatus

PS> Get-SmbSession | ft ClientComputerName,ClientUserName,Dialect
```